# Selenium IDE : Table item containing dynamic id

Tags: selenium-ide

I am a novice Selenium IDE user.  I am attempting to “click on” an item in a table whose ID is dynamic; it changes when new items are added or dropped from the table.  The specific item in question is identified at the end of the HTML code below [td id="GroupsNotAssigned_LBI2T0"].  The text of the item associated with the id is [NPM Read Write Data and Read Only Reserves].

Thanks in advance for the help
Using Selenium IDE 2.9
USING Firefox 42.0

```
<td id="frmProfile_4_2" class="dxflGroupCell">
<table class="dxflCLTSys dxflItemSys dxflCustomItemSys dxflItem" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="dxflHALSys dxflVATSys dxflCaptionCell dxflCaptionCellSys" style="width: 98px;">
<label class="dxflCaption">Not a member of:</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dxflNestedControlCellSys dxflNestedControlCell">
<input id="GroupsNotAssignedDeletedItems" type="hidden" value="" name="GroupsNotAssignedDeletedItems">
<input id="GroupsNotAssignedInsertedItems" type="hidden" value="" name="GroupsNotAssignedInsertedItems">
<input id="GroupsNotAssignedCustomCallback" type="hidden" value="" name="GroupsNotAssignedCustomCallback">
<table id="GroupsNotAssigned" class="dxeListBox_BFS2014 " cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height:250px;width:250px;border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="GroupsNotAssigned_D" class="dxlbd" style="height: 246px; width: 248px; overflow: auto;" tabindex="-1">
<input id="GroupsNotAssigned_VI" type="hidden" name="GroupsNotAssigned" value="113">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;visibility:hidden!important;display:none!important;">
<tbody>
<tr id="GroupsNotAssigned_LBI-1" class="dxeListBoxItemRow_BFS2014">
<td id="GroupsNotAssigned_LBI-1T0" class="dxeListBoxItem_BFS2014"> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="GroupsNotAssigned_LBT" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: separate;">
<tbody>
<tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow_BFS2014">
<tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow_BFS2014">
<tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow_BFS2014">
<td id="GroupsNotAssigned_LBI2T0" class="dxeListBoxItem_BFS2014">NPM Read Write Data and Read Only Reserves</td>
</tr>
```

[image of code[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggQlJ.png)]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to do but it looks like this should work:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//td[contains(@id,"GroupsNotAssigned_LBI"]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks ... my problem is that the "2" in the LBI... string is dynamic ... sometimes it is 2 and other times it may be some other integer ... I have been trying to figure out how to reach the title "NPM Read Write Data and Read Only Reserves" but I can't seem to find the right target.

Comment: I edited my answer to what I think you're asking for dynamic: This we only check for GroupsNotAssigned_LBI so the 2TO can be anything.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  My problem is that the "GroupsNotAssigned_LBI" tag covers a list of items; each item is designated by an integer but the integer changes as a user interacts with the list of items.  The test involves selecting an item from the list and moving it to another table in the application.Thanks again. @DMart

Comment: So then you want to grab that integer earlier in the tests?
And then look for it in the last later on?

Comment: if that's the case then you need to "store" that as a variable and then look for it later on:
<td>//td[@id,"${my_variable}"</td>

Comment: I do not  know how to locate what I need to select without using the LBIstring (LBI4TO in the string below) .  The integer in the string is dynamic so I can't seem to use that.  When I use the "find" feature of Selenium IDE (and the element selector in firebug)  the list item I am trying to "click" shows as: <td id="GroupsNotAssigned_LBI4T0" class="dxeListBoxItem_BFS2014 dxeListBoxItemSelected_BFS2014">NPM Edit Data and Read Only Reserves</td>         I think I need to "tag" the title 'NPM Edit Data and Read Only Reserves" but I do not seem to be able to target it in IDE @DMart